# Route all traffic through TUN interface

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, linux-networking, tun

I want all my traffic go through `TUN` interface.

[image: Here is the flowchart]

So, as you can see, the traffic is routed to `TUN` iface on `10.0.0.1` address from every program. Then, the program attached to the `TUN` does something with the packets, and then they are sent to my router on `192.168.1.1`. Then they're routed across the Internet (for example, to my proxy server, but it doesn't actually matter that much for my problem).

So my goal is just to route traffic in that manner: `$any_program` <--> `tunX` <--> `192.168.1.1 (the router)` (`<-->` thing means that traffic goes both in and out).

What I've did so far:

1. First, I initialized `tunX` device with this function:

```c
int tun_open(char *device)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;
    
    fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("opening /dev/net/tun");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, device, IFNAMSIZ);
    
    err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr);
    if (err == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl TUNSETIFF");
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    return fd;
}
```

And then:

```c
tunfd = tun_open("tun6");
```

Also, I enabled `TUNSETPERSIST`:

```c
ioctl(tunfd, TUNSETPERSIST, 1) < 0);
```

2. Then, I set up the device with following commands:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun6
$ sudo ip link set tun6 up
```

The program reads from `tunfd` and outputs the content. So far the only thing it reads is the following:

```
:B\{k
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover" 
MX: 1
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
USER-AGENT: Google Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Linux

%   N%*.%K%M%P%M%M%M%HP%,%M%*K%(aP%>O%M%LqP%@K%`P%P%Ҵ u@=U繤湤}=UoK%0=U
```

ssdp:discover? Why is this getting through my tun interface?

Output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

I've been playing around with `iptables` and `ip route` programs, but I'm kind of a newbie in all these. As far as I understood, `iptables` doesn't actually route the packets, but filter them (I can be very wrong). So is there a way to route the packets with `ip route`?

Comment: You need to provide much more details like type of tunnel used, commands you typed to create the tunnel, and routes configured and so on. We can't just help you without these details.

Comment: @Khaled I've made changes to my post, please consider!

Comment: Where does the tunnel even terminate? It needs to connect two endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Normal routing is based on destinations, not interfaces (unless you configure policy-based routing), therefore you need to route all outbound traffic to the `10.0.0.0/24` network:

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 10.0.0.254
```

Actually it doesn't matter through which address in `10.0.0.0/24` you send it, it should reach your program.

Comment: So in every platform after creating tun interface you should set the route too?

Comment: If you want to route **all** traffic through that device yes. If you just want to reach a subnetwork through that device, the `ip addr add` command will also set up a route for you.