# Unable to route all traffic through openconnect vpn

Tags: vpn, routing

*Feel free to give me a course correction. I'm out of my depth here.*

I'm using openconnect to connect to a vpn. This creates a device `tun0`, which I can see when I run `ip address`. I've successfully added entries to my routing table with `ip route add $IP_ADDR dev tun0` and been able to access servers on my vpn.

I want to try using this vpn connection as my default route, and I've seen other posts, such as the following two, which instruct me to perform a command like this: `ip route add default via 192.168.30.1 dev mydevice`

- [Route all traffic through TUN interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048393/route-all-traffic-through-tun-interface)
- [How to route all traffic through vpn adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065397/how-to-route-all-traffic-through-vpn-adapter)

Well, I've tried something similar, but I omit the `via $IP_ADDR` because I can't find an ip address for this device:

```sh
dhclient tun0 # => outputs nothing
ip route del default
ip route add default dev tun0
```

...and when I do so, it appears that I can't connect to any servers at all. If I add a route that uses `tun0` to my routing table *without* making it the default route, though, I can reach servers on the vpn for as many routing rules as I've created.

*Edit: here's the output of `ip route show` (before trying to change the default):* https://pastebin.com/0X9rqgne

Comment: What are the details for the VPN server? Is it set up by someone else? Have you set it up? How does the VPN server provision IP addresses?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen the VPN server is set up by IT at my employer, and they're an impenetrable group. I connect to it with `openconnect --protocol=anyconnect --user=$ME $VPN_DOMAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do three steps:

Add a route to the VPN server via your physical gateway so that VPN tunnel packets can reach the VPN server

```
ip route add <VPN server IP address> via 192.168.68.1
```

Delete existing default route

```
ip route delete default via 192.168.68.1
```

Add default route via the tunnel

```
ip route add default dev tun0
```

However, if the VPN server doesn't forward packets to the internet, then adding this configuration doesn't help. In that case, you need to convince the VPN server operators to forward traffic to the internet.

There are legitimate reasons why the VPN server wouldn't forward traffic to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev tun0
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting no internet when after running that command. Is there more to it?

Comment: can you add the output of `ip route` to the original post?

Comment: Added (link to pastebin)

Comment: did you manually add all those routes?

Comment: Yes, I manually added all of those `tun0` routes (but not the other routes).

Comment: `ip route del default via 192.168.68.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev tun0`

Comment: please dont paste on nopadte bor as comment such information. you can and have to edit the question to add them

Comment: This is still a no-go. After failing with that I command, I even flushed my entire routing table (`ip r flush table 0`) and added only the rule you specified, but I still can't reach any servers.

Answer (score 0):

My university's VPN (Cisco) forces split tunneling. I was able to force all my traffic to be tunneled through the VPN. This answer is written for Mac, but might apply to all unix systems.

1. First I had to install the vpnc-script, as described [here](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/vpnc-script.html). You can get a current version of the script from [here](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/raw/master/vpnc-script). Save it somewhere on your drive, I saved it to `/opt/local/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script`.
2. As it turns out, the newest versions of the script have an issue that prevents them from working on new versions of MacOS (Montenery), as described [here](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/issues/45). The solution was replacing the newest version with an older one, specifically with [this](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/raw/92fe06f6589dcc21725c51b8f86051482bf3b1bd/vpnc-script).
3. As described in [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/732331/1038358), insert the following line in the downloaded vpnc-script to unset the CISCO_SPLIT_INC variable.

```bash
# ...
# =========== script (variable) setup ====================================

# Insert this line:
CISCO_SPLIT_INC=
```

4. Connect to the VPN via openconnect and specify that the script should be run: 
   `sudo openconnect --script="/opt/local/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script" --protocol=anyconnect -u <username> https://<university-domain>`